# How to show date on bottomTitle in fl_chart

Tags: flutter, dart, fl-chart

So I'm having a hard time figuring out how to show the date I'm getting from my PHP Script into FlChart.

The data I get from my PHP Script looks like this, so basically what this means is that I get an average value on the day it was measured on.

```
[
  {
    "Datum": "Sun",
    "Avg": 166
  },
  {
    "Datum": "Mon",
    "Avg": 333
  },
  {
    "Datum": "Sat",
    "Avg": 123
  }
]
```

My class looks like this

```
class AvgDataBaseData {
  final int? avg;
  final String? date;
  AvgDataBaseData({this.avg, this.date});
  factory AvgDataBaseData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return AvgDataBaseData(avg: json['Avg'], date: json['Datum']);
  }
}
```

Code to show my line-chart

```
class AvgDataBaseList extends StatelessWidget {
  const AvgDataBaseList({super.key, required this.AvgDataBases});
  final List<AvgDataBaseData> AvgDataBases;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<FlSpot> spots = AvgDataBases.asMap().entries.map((e) {
      return FlSpot(e.key.toDouble(), e.value.avg!.toDouble());
    }).toList();

    SideTitles _bottomTitles() {
      return SideTitles(
        showTitles: true,
        getTitlesWidget: (value, meta) {
          var date = AvgDataBases.asMap().entries.map((e) => Text(e.value.date.toString()),).toList();
          return SideTitleWidget(axisSide: meta.axisSide, child: Text(date.toString()));
        },
      );
    }

    return Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
        child: LineChart(LineChartData(
          borderData: borderData,
          titlesData: FlTitlesData(
            show: true,
            bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
              sideTitles: _bottomTitles(),
            ),
            leftTitles: AxisTitles(
              sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
            ),
            topTitles: AxisTitles(
              sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
            ),
            rightTitles: AxisTitles(
              sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
            ),
          ),
          lineBarsData: [
            LineChartBarData(
                barWidth: 5,
                spots: spots,
                isCurved: true,
                gradient: LinearGradient(colors: gradientColors),
                belowBarData: BarAreaData(
                    show: true,
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: gradientColors
                          .map((color) => color.withOpacity(0.3))
                          .toList(),
                    )))
          ],
          //to deactive the grid
          gridData: gridData,
          //titlesData: titlesData)),
          // titlesData: FlTitlesData(
          //     rightTitles: AxisTitles(
          //       sideTitles: SideTitles(
          //         showTitles: true,
          //         reservedSize: 40,
          //       ),
          //     ),
          //     show: false))),
        )));
  }
}
```

I'm able to show the average value in my linechart, but I'm unable to show the date the average value was measured on. I tried returning the SideTitleWidget like this

```
SideTitles _bottomTitles() {
      return SideTitles(
        showTitles: true,
        getTitlesWidget: (value, meta) {
          var date = AvgDataBases.asMap().entries.map((e) => Text(e.value.date.toString()),).toList();
          return SideTitleWidget(axisSide: meta.axisSide, child: Text(date.toString()));
        },
      );
    }
```

but this doesn't work like i want it.

Comment: btw I cant find any limit on your chart

Comment: because I dont have one at the moment

Comment: well you need it fist, I am using max value from list for test

Comment: just used a interval of 7 and it is already looking better

Comment: You can have `interval` on  `SideTitles`

Comment: https://ibb.co/BqDmYDq. It looks like this atm

Comment: Try my post and color and border modification, you will get there.

Comment: ty everything is working, it helped me alot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to provide some theses parameters

```dart
 LineChartData(
          minX: 0,
          maxX: AvgDataBases.length.toDouble(),
          minY: 0,
          maxY: maxY.toDouble(),
```

And bottomTitles will be

```dart
    SideTitles _bottomTitles() {
      return SideTitles(
        showTitles: true,
        interval: 1,
        getTitlesWidget: (value, meta) {
          var date = value.toInt() < AvgDataBases.length
              ? AvgDataBases[value.toInt()].date
              : "";
          return SideTitleWidget(axisSide: meta.axisSide, child: Text("$date"));
        },
      );
    }
```

Test snippet

```dart
class AvgDataBaseList extends StatelessWidget {
  // const AvgDataBaseList({super.key, required this.AvgDataBases});
  final List<AvgDataBaseData> AvgDataBases = [
    AvgDataBaseData(avg: 166, date: "Sun"),
    AvgDataBaseData(avg: 333, date: "Mon"),
    AvgDataBaseData(avg: 123, date: "Sat"),
  ];

  late final maxY = AvgDataBases.map((e) => e.avg ?? 0).toList().reduce(max); // import dart:math
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<FlSpot> spots = AvgDataBases.asMap().entries.map((e) {
      return FlSpot(e.key.toDouble(), e.value.avg!.toDouble());
    }).toList();

    SideTitles _bottomTitles() {
      return SideTitles(
        showTitles: true,
        interval: 1,
        getTitlesWidget: (value, meta) {
          var date = value.toInt() < AvgDataBases.length
              ? AvgDataBases[value.toInt()].date
              : "";
          return SideTitleWidget(axisSide: meta.axisSide, child: Text("$date"));
        },
      );
    }

    return Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
        child: LineChart(LineChartData(
          minX: 0,
          maxX: AvgDataBases.length.toDouble(),
          minY: 0,
          maxY: maxY.toDouble(),
          baselineX: 4,
          titlesData: FlTitlesData(
            show: true,
            bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
              sideTitles: _bottomTitles(),
            ),
            leftTitles: AxisTitles(
              sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
            ),
            topTitles: AxisTitles(
              sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
            ),
            rightTitles: AxisTitles(
              sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
            ),
          ),
          lineBarsData: [
            LineChartBarData(
              barWidth: 5,
              spots: spots,
              isCurved: true,
              belowBarData: BarAreaData(
                show: true,
              ),
            )
          ],
        )));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: ty for ur answer, I just tried ur solution and it still looks like a mess

Comment: Actually I didn't test while setUp will be a little lengthy, it works this similar way, let me test